# Dividing country into regions based on some initial center point using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, splitting, point-in-polygon

I am new to GIS.

I have some lat-long (say 5) spreads across a country and I want to make polygons around each point such that all the polygons cover the whole area of the country and within the polygon, its aerial distance is minimum compared to other points.

A rough illustration is shown in image.

[image: A rough illustration]

Comment: (1) Create [Buffers](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) around Points > (2) [Union](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) your country polygon with the result of step (1). Otherwise apply [Voronoi-Thiessen Polygons](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/create-thiessen-polygons.htm).

Comment: Thanks!! @Taras This is useful.

Comment: Try to implement some of above ideas and show your efforts here on GIS SE, people will be pleased